# Proper lens for filming walking mouse in 33 inch-long cat walk

Tags: lens

For biomedical research, I need to video a mouse walking through a 33 inch catwalk with a high speed camera (Basler acA1300-200um, USB 3.0, sensor size 6.1 mm x 4.9 mm).

Because I will later analyse the video with special software, I need an image unaffected by lens optical aberrations.

I tried to use a Carl Zeiss Makro-Planar T* 60mm C f/2.8 (C/Y), but the subject to lens distance (mouse to the camera) is too far (more than 20 feet) to capture the whole field.

The model of the camera I am using is the Basler acA1300-200um, USB 3.0. It has a sensor size of 6.1 mm x 4.9 mm. The spec can be found here: https://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/cameras/area-scan-cameras/ace/aca1300-200um/

What would be a good lens for this task?

Comment: What you're probably actually wanting to avoid is geometric distortion, rather than spherical aberration. (you certainly want to avoid SA also). But I think what you are trying to describe is the "fisheye effect"of the way some lenses project very wide angle scenes.

Comment: It seems you're talking about fisheye effect, the issue is the close you want to be but still be able to capture the entire frame, the more you need to zoom out. The result of this is "fisheye" which can be worked on in post to a large degree however to my knowledge isn't something you can perfectly deal with other than in post.

Comment: @Matthew Projection is a function of a lens' design and is not directly determined by focal length alone. It does become more difficult to make very wide angle lenses with rectilinear projection. In the FF world, there are fisheye lenses as long as 15mm and rectilinear lenses as short as 10-11mm. There are APS-C rectilinear lenses at least as short as 8mm.

Comment: Video questions are more appropriate at video.stackexchange.com. This community is concerned with still imaging. There are a few "video" questions that also have application to still imaging, and some older "video" questions here that were asked before the separate video community was established. But new questions devoted entirely to video should be asked over there.

Comment: @MichaelClark This could be a lens/sensor-size/field size type question that is often asked/answered here

Comment: @Stan In which case it's a duplicate to at least a dozen questions, including some that give formulas for figuring it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First -- I was not aware that Balser made a film camera. Could it be that your are interchanging the word "film" for video?

I strongly suggest that for now, ignore lens quality deficiencies such as aberrations until after you nail down the camera and lens combination that will best do this task. Let me add that I doubt that lens aberrations of any kind will be a deterrent. In other words, modern camera lenses are generally good to go for most projects (exceptions noted).

The focal length of a lens dictates the size of images of object and the angle of view. Reading between the lines, you found that the 60mm yielded too much magnification and too narrow a field of view forcing you to step back to 20 feet.

Now subject distance and focal length are intertwined proportionally. If you mount a 30mm, the field of view will widen and the image size will half. In other words, mount a 30mm and you can image form 10 feet. Mount a 15mm and you can move in to 5 feet. Their are limits as how short a lens you can mount. The danger is, too short a lens and the image will be vignette (dark corners).

Comment: Thank you Alan. I notice that the spec of the M0814-MP2 lens state it is for 2/3 inch sensors. Will it be OK for 6.1 mm x 4.9 mm sensor of the Basler camera I already have?

Comment: @ Aldrin -- Industry practice is to fit a lens that delivers a "normal" view. This will be a focal length about equal to the diagonal measure of the sensor. This sensor measures 7.85. Thus the 8mm is a best match. Such a lash-up will give you a camera placement of about 3 feet.

Comment: Alan, I truly appreciate your help. I will get the lens you have recommend me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Aldrin - I moved these comments to Alan's answer for you.  Also, if Alan's answer met your needs, please consider using the checkmark next to his answer to indicate that it solved your problem.